# Solving running time of T(n)=2T(n/2)+nlogn

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, master-theorem

I'm trying to solve this in a certain way ,I already know that its complexity is BigTheta(nloglogn) ,but i don't get the same answer if i do the following:

```
let m = logn
then n = 2^m
we get T(2^m) = 2T(2^(m-1))+(2^m)*m
multiply by 1/(2^m)
we get T(2^m)/2^m = 2T(2^(m-1))/2^m + m
= T(2^(m-1))/(2^(m-1)) + m
```

Now if i let `S(m)=T(2^m)/2^m` I will have `S(m)=S(m-1)+m`.

Now I solve `S(m)=S(m-1)+m` by back substitution method.

```
S(m) = S(m-1)+m=S(m-2)+(m-1)+m = S(m-3)+(m-2)+(m-1)+m = S(m-4)+(m-3)+(m-2)+(m-1)+m=... = S(m-k)+(m-k+1)+..+(m-3)+(m-2)+(m-1)+m = ... = S(1)+2+...+m = m(m-1)/2 = BigTheta(m^2)
```

Plugging back `m=logn` and i get `BigTheta((logn)^2)` which is not the same.

Comment: The correct answer is BigTheta(n*lognlogn) and not BigTheta(n*loglogn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have followed the right approach my friend. There's a slight mistake though.

```
S(m) = S(m-1) + m
```

which is correct and we get `S(m) = BigTheta(m^2)`.

Now `S(m) = T(2^m)/(2^m) = BigTheta(m^2)` . This means `T(2^m) = T(n) = (2^m) * BigTheta(m^2)`.

Putting back the values we get `T(n) = n*BigTheta(lognlogn) = BigTheta(n*lognlogn)`

Comment: Just one thing to make sure of isn't logn*log=(logn)^2 and log^2(n)=loglogn or am i mistaken here ?

Comment: @user3100258 In logn*log, the second log(the one without n) has nothing to take log of. It must be a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the error here is in this line:

> Now if I let `S(m)=T(2^m)/2^m` I will have `S(m)=S(m-1)+m`.

In fact, if you let `S(m)=T(2^m)/2^m`, then you will have `S(m)=2S(m-1)+m`, because of the division by `2^(m-1)`.

With this correction we have:

```
S(m) = 2S(m - 1) + m
     = 2S(2S(m - 2) + m) + m
     = 4S(m - 2) + (m − 1) + m
     = 4S(2S(m - 3) + (m - 2)) + (m − 1) + m
     = 8S(m - 3) + (m - 2) + (m - 1) + m
```

This gives us the general form:

```
S(m) = 2^m S(0) + m(m+1)/2
```

Plugging back in, we have then that:

```
T(2^m) = 2^m T(0) + m(m+1) 2^(m-1)
```

Then we can plug back in for n:

```
T(n) = nT(1) + n/2 (logn)(1 + logn) = O(n(logn)^2)
```

Comment: Forgive me but isn't `2S(m-1)=2*(T(2^m-1)/2^m-1) but 2*(T(2^m-1)/2^m-1)` is equal to `4T(2^m-1)/2^m` which is not `2T(2^m-1)/2^m` ,am i missing something?